# Conditional filter for MySQL query

Tags: sql, mysql, conditional-statements

I've got a query that looks like this:

```
select a.title, is.filename
  from articles a
  join article_images ai on ai.article_id = a.article_id
  join images i on i.image_id = ai.image_id
  join image_sizes is on is.image_id = i.image_id
 where is.size_name = '96x96';
```

So there is an N:N relationship between articles and images, and an N:1 relationship between images and image sizes. This selects the 96x96 image for each article.

Now I want to change this so it selects the 96x96 image, *unless* the `article_id` is 42, in which case it selects a different size. Is there a way to do that in one query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change to this:

```
where (a.article_id <> 42 AND is.size_name = '96x96')
   OR (a.article_id = 42 AND is.size_name = 'something different')
```

Comment: This will certainly work, but worth noting that using UNION as suggested in other answers should be slightly faster in MySQL. OR can prevent indexes being used.

Comment: Thanks, this works great. The `UNION` answer is also good, but I'm more interested in readability than efficiency in this case, and this makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should separate your query into two queries: query for 96x96 and query for article_id=42. Then you should UNION this two results. It will also help you to keep your queries clean and readable.

Comment: though it might have better performance, I wouldn't say the query would be cleaner, more readable or easier to maintain...

Answer (score 1):

```
(select a.title, is.filename
  from articles a
  join article_images ai on ai.article_id = a.article_id
  join images i on i.image_id = ai.image_id
  join image_sizes is on is.image_id = i.image_id
 where is.size_name = '96x96' and a.article_id <> 42)
union all
(select a.title, is.filename
  from articles a
  join article_images ai on ai.article_id = a.article_id
  join images i on i.image_id = ai.image_id
  join image_sizes is on is.image_id = i.image_id
 where is.size_name = 'Some other size' and a.article_id = 42)
```

You will need to replace 'some other size' with whatever the other size is, or use a SELECT TOP 1 and a GROUP BY in the second query if you don't know the size.